# What is the quantum mechanical interaction cross section of a photon during scattering of photons by electrons present in metals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I don't how to calculate interaction cross section for this process.Can I use Thomson cross section for this process because this process is similar to Thomson scattering,if not ,How to calculate interaction cross section for this process?.

Comment: Normally, one would use a quantum computation of the conductivity of the metal (e.g. with Kubo formula), but I am curious how to deal with scattering from bound electrons. I imagine it would be similar to scattering from electrons in a dielectric.

Comment: I am talking about the free electrons in metals,that is conduction electrons.any idea about that.?.

Comment: Conduction electrons are still bound to the metal. This process would fall under the general heading of the photoelectric effect I would think. Perhaps there's some insight to be gained from literature about that?

Comment: Oh, right, and the method you use will depend on the general frequency range of interest.

Comment: @Anns, if you can get a copy, consult Chapter 10 of Solid State Physics by Giuseppe Grosso. He goes over the Thomson scattering of electrons by X-ray and then adds some refinement.

Comment: Also, I think the picture of Thomson scattering works only for X-ray, in typical metals, because the X-ray energy is much greater than any other interaction felt by the electron due to others (ions, phonons), so you can ignore those weaker interactions and only consider free electron + light interaction. If your light is not in X-ray but much weaker, you have to treat it as a perturbation to the (electron + ion +phonon) system. Most likely you have to work with a dielectric function.

Comment: What is the cross section for infrared photons?@Gilbert

Comment: What is the cross section for scattering due to electrons in metals?.please answer.